# Fill in missing dates in date range from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
table A
no  date        count
1   20160401    1
1   20160403    4
2   20160407    3
```

```
result
no  date        count
1   20160401    1
1   20160402    0
1   20160403    4
1   20160404    0
.
.
.
2   20160405    0
2   20160406    0
2   20160407    3
.
.
.
```

I'm using Oracle and I want to write a query that returns rows for every date within a range based on table A.

Is there some function in Oracle that can help me?

Comment: There's a good chance there's already an answer on Stack Overflow. Surely there must be a way to join to a calendar table between date *x* and *y* and join your results to that? I couldn't find it though. Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable in the Oracle tag can! :)

Comment: Just to clarify. These are tables and the not the result of a group-by/aggregate query?

Comment: What's your requirement? + What have you tried? Have you actually written some query or have attempted to do so to achieve the result you seek? If so, please share that. Also if possible, please explain the logic that is required to structure the data output in plain english (+technical jargons if you wish to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with 
  A as (
    select 1 no, to_date('20160401', 'yyyymmdd') dat, 1 cnt from dual union all
    select 1 no, to_date('20160403', 'yyyymmdd') dat, 4 cnt from dual union all
    select 2 no, to_date('20160407', 'yyyymmdd') dat, 3 cnt from dual),
  B as (select min(dat) mindat, max(dat) maxdat from A t),
  C as (select level + mindat - 1 dat from B connect by level + mindat - 1 <= maxdat),
  D as (select distinct no from A),
  E as (select * from D,C)
select E.no, E.dat, nvl(cnt, 0) cnt
from E
full outer join A on A.no = E.no and A.dat = E.dat
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `SEQUENCES`.

First create a sequence

```
 Create Sequence seq_name start with 20160401 max n;
```

where n is the max value till u want to display.

Then use the sql

```
 select seq_name.next,case when seq_name.next = date then count else 0 end from tableA;
```

Note:- Its better not to use date,count as the column names.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an oracle specific answer, you'll need to translate it to oracle yourself.

Create an intervals table, containing all integers from 0 to 999. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE intervals (days int);
INSERT INTO intervals (days) VALUES (0), (1);
DECLARE @rc int;
SELECT @rc = 2;
WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM intervals) < 1000 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO intervals (days) SELECT days + @rc FROM intervals WHERE days + @rc < 1000;
    SELECT @rc = @rc * 2
END;
```

Then all the dates in the range can be identified by adding intervals.days to the first date you've got, where the first date + intervals.days is <= the end date, and the resultant date is new. Do this by cross joining intervals to your own table. Something like (it would be in SQL, but again you'll need to translate):

```
SELECT DateAdd(a.date, d, i.days)
FROM (select min(date) from table_A) a, intervals I
WHERE DateAdd(a.date, d, i.days) < (select max(date) from table_A)
    AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table_A aa where aa.date = DateAdd(a.date, d, i.days))
```

Hope this gives you a starting point